# Getting image name without extension from an image path in javascript

Tags: javascript, image, path

I have this image URL, how I can get only the image name without the extension. Noting that the folder name of date and the image name structure is changeable. the image name could start with characters.

```
imageURL = "http://127.0.0.1:2222//ImagesDB/images/2003-09-18/**20131010_130014_123**.jpg";
```

the image name I need is like s"`20131010_130014_123`"

I found some solutions over StackOverflow but is not solving my case.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use regex:

```js
var imageURL = "http://127.0.0.1:2222//ImagesDB/images/2003-09-18/20131010_130014_123.jpg";

var imageName = imageURL.match(/\w*(?=.\w+$)/);

console.log(imageName);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like that:

```
const imageName = imageURL.substring(imageURL.lastIndexOf('/')+1, imageURL.lastIndexOf('.'));
```